# Pandas change date to MMM-YY format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of dates in the format: 2023-03-31 00:00:00, how can I change this to MMM-YY format? MAR-23 using the provided example.

Comment: did you do some research, try something? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59476012/10197418 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_name']).dt.strftime('%b-%y')
```

Comment: How can I get the same result if I have multi-index columns? i.e.  (2023-03-31 00:00:00, 'foo'),(2023-03-31 00:00:00, 'bar') ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).